# php json_encode producess in correct characters to display

Tags: php, unicode

If I echo the following variable below, the characters are displayed without problems.

```
echo $characters['column1'];
```

However, if I echo out the array variable, the characters come out with a different character set when using `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode($characters);
```

PHP vervsion is 5.3.3

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Working as intended, just `json_decode()` and you'll see there's no problem. It's standard practice for it to escape characters that aren't in ASCII format so you'll get like `\u104A` for instance.

Comment: Can you show the output of the code.